Using alias from before() in a it() test
In this example on the website, they say there is a simple way to use data you create in before() or beforeEach() in a testcase it(). But when I tried it it said my this.variable was undefined. After a little more searching I found that all aliases are cleared before each test, making the example on the website not possible.
Example on the website under Sharing context:
describe('parent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.wrap('one').as('a')
  })

  context('child', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.wrap('two').as('b')
    })

    describe('grandchild', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        cy.wrap('three').as('c')
      })

      it('can access all aliases as properties', function () {
        expect(this.a).to.eq('one') // true
        expect(this.b).to.eq('two') // true
        expect(this.c).to.eq('three') // true
      })
    })
  })
})

Briefly what I'm trying to do (I thought the way I get my data irrelevant to the question):
describe('myTests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // producing data resulting in a jquery list element
    cy.wrap($element).as('element')
  })

  it('firstTest', function () {
    this.element.click()
  })
}

This results on a TypeError (void 0) is undefined with an error to the beginning of this
edit:
So what I'm doing is getting a list element from a website. The second visible element in the main menu.
describe('Click test', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        let counter = 0
        cy.visit('https://www.qalybr.nl')
        cy.get('ul[class~=menu] li').each(($el) => {
            if($el.is(':visible')) {
                if(counter === 1) {
                    cy.wrap($el).as('werkenBij')
                }
                counter++;
            }
        })
    })

    it('Werken', () => {
        this.werkenBij.click()
    })
})

It wraps and aliases the element correctly, the cypress runner shows this, but then isn't able to find this.


How do you define $element?
the doc says:
cy.get('').then(($element) => {
cy.wrap($element).as('element')
}

You may want to consider using an alternate Alias as element could interfere with a property of this that already exists. Please provide a [mcve].

The full example in the edit section is different to the example given above it.
To use the this.werkenBij form of alias you must have a function() based callback, not a () => {} arrow-function based callback.
  it('Werken', function() {
    this.werkenBij.click()
  })



It does actually depend on the way you are obtaining $element. If you follow the pattern in the documents you quoted, there is no problem.
This passes
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.get'some-selector-for-button').as('element')
})

it('uses element alias', function() {
  this.element.click()                
})

and of course this passes
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.get'some-selector-for-button').as('element')
})

it('uses element alias', function() {
  cy.get('@element').click()                
})

Cypress tells you (on the linked page) that you should not use the return value from a query, because it may go stale.
So don't do this
// BAD CODE

beforeEach(() => {
  const $element = cy.get'some-selector-for-button')
  cy.wrap($element).as('element')
})

it('uses element alias', function() {
  this.element.click()                
})

Always chain the alias instead, even if you are working with $element inside a then()
// GOOD CODE

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.get'some-selector-for-button')
    .then($element => {
      const $elementText = $element.text()

      // use the text in some way

      return $element    // return the element for capturing in the alias
    })
    .as('element')
})

it('uses element alias', function() {
  this.element.click()                
})

